# Spring Batch and Spring TaskScheduler

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, scheduled-tasks, spring-batch

So I have two jobs with separate tasklets each.

**JobA** will do:

```
sysout("JobA executed at "+new Date());
```

**JobB** will do:

```
sysout("JobB executed at "+new Date());
```

Both of which can either be in a separate xml or in one xml. But I am currently have separate xml for both. I defined both jobs with the same way like this:

```
<batch:job id="task_scheduler" restartable="false">
    <batch:step id="test_task_scheduler"
        allow-start-if-complete="true">
        <batch:tasklet ref="job1" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="job1" class="com.irsis.batch.tasklet.TestOut" />
<bean id="runScheduler" class="com.irsis.batch.taskscheduler.RunScheduler1" />
```

Then at my `application-context.xml` I defined the task scheduler

```
    <task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler1" method="run"
        cron="*0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? " />
    <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler2" method="run"
        cron="0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? "/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

When running I have this exception

```
Could not autowire field: org.springframework.batch.core.Job com.irsis.batch.taskscheduler.RunScheduler1.job; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.Job] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: task_scheduler,task_scheduler2
```

btw, this is my RunScheduler1.java file

```
@Autowired 
JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired 
Job job;

public void run() {


    try {

        String dateParam = new Date().toString();
        JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("date",
                dateParam).toJobParameters();

        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
        System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Done");

}
```

Now my question is it possible for spring batch to have multiple jobs? Because from what I'm seeing from my exception is that it's only expecting a single job.

Though I tried another way. What I did was something like this in the application-context.xml

```
<batch:job id="job" restartable="false">
    <batch:step id="test_task_scheduler"
        allow-start-if-complete="true">
        <batch:tasklet ref="job1" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="job1" class="com.irsis.batch.tasklet.TestOut" />
<bean id="runScheduler1" class="com.irsis.batch.taskscheduler.RunScheduler1" />


    <batch:job id="job2" restartable="false">
    <batch:step id="test_task2_scheduler"
        allow-start-if-complete="true">
        <batch:tasklet ref="job2" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="job2" class="com.irsis.batch.tasklet.TestOut2" />
<bean id="runScheduler2" class="com.irsis.batch.taskscheduler.RunScheduler2" />


<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler1" method="run"
        cron="*0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? " />

</task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler2" method="run"
        cron="0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? " />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

It ran the first job then whenever it tried to run the 2nd job this exception appears:

> PreparedStatementCallback; 
>   SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION)
>   values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "job_inst_un"   Detail: Key (job_name, job_key)=(job,
>   8a87688793625c6f3b8f982dbe6689d2) already exists.; nested exception is
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates
>   unique constraint "job_inst_un"   Detail: Key (job_name,
>   job_key)=(job, 8a87688793625c6f3b8f982dbe6689d2) already exists.

UPDATE: I think I'm gonna change my approach. Another question link[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521046/spring-taskscheduler)

Thanks,
Jet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a Spring batch exception, it is more of a normal Spring wiring exception. The reason is you probably have an `@Autowired` annotation for `Job` property in your `RunScheduler1`. Now in your context you end up having two jobs the one with id of `task_scheduler` and one with a id of `task_scheduler2` and Spring does not know which specific one you want to wire in.

A simple fix will be to simply remove `@Autowired` and inject the reference in through xml this way:

```
<bean id="runScheduler" class="com.irsis.batch.taskscheduler.RunScheduler1" >
    <property name="job" ref="task_scheduler"/>
</bean>
```

*Update:*
Your unique constraint related exception is actually possible - two jobs are considered the same if the parameters for both jobs match up exactly, in your case somehow the dates are clashing(there is I feel a small bug here with Spring batch because of the precision of toString method of Date) for two different job instances and hence the issue. Can I suggest may be adding one more parameter (say your custom UUID using `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`), this will ensure that the two job parameters are absolutely unique and should be considered as two totally different job instances.

Comment: hi @BijuKunjummen I edited my question. I added the RunScheduler1.java file for reference.

Comment: scratch my previous comments. was able to run the project but then whenever it starting to execute the jobs, it would catch an exception. "The Job must not be null."

Comment: May I recommend simply closing your current question and reopening for your specific issue - now you have mentioned 3 different issues and I have provided answers for 2 of them.

Comment: followed your advice. thanks for the answers. provided the new question link at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing the same job parameter again and again... for running the job.
Try to change your job parameter for each run.

like--

```
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
          .addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis())
          .toJobParameters();

JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is spring injection issue.Their might be some conflict in the name reference.You might need to use @Qualifier to work around this issue.Please check this link.http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-autowiring-qualifier-example/